# Authenticate PC's using PHP

Tags: php, authentication

I have developed a web based portal using php and some part of the site is only accessible by employees only. I would like to add an extra security layer so only employees whose PC is authenticated can access the restricted area.

If it was Dot NET it could be easily done by using activex components but I am not certain about the PHP.

Can any one share hints how to accomplish this task using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Active Directory to Authenticate? If so, you can probably tap into the LDAP functions in order to check for a valid authentication.  You could also implement some security paradigm like Kerberos in order to achieve this with single sign on.

The easiest thing to do is to add a users table to your database and then built some basic authentication around that.

Comment: +1 for AD/LDAP if it's running.  I found this (unvetted) component http://phpad.sunyday.net/ as well as a litany of blog posts...

Comment: Can it be done using a card reader. I remember my bank has given me a card and card reader, when I put my card into card reader that card reader generates a number and when I put that number on web page it authneticate my transaction, just wondering if there is any generic card readers for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a *while-list* with the IP's of the allowed computers (using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`), since it's almost the only information that you can obtain from the machine that make the HTTP request using just server-side scripting.

This should work well for computers inside the company, since they would have IP's within the same range (e.g. `10.100.x.x` or `192.168.x.x`), or they will use the same gateway for connecting to Internet.

If you need to allow access to roaming laptops, then this method will be almost useless unless they have static IP addresses.

Comment: employees are located in different countries and their ips changes frequently.

Answer (score 0):

This likely isn't possible with PHP. You can try to embed an ActiveX control using PHP, but I feel like this would be a better application for desktop software. PHP is definitely not going to be sympathetic. Sorry.